# How to bold text in a QTextBrowser?

Tags: python, text, qgis

I'm new to QGIS and Python and I want to know how to bold some text in a QTextBrowser. I'm using Ubuntu. I just tried these in the QGIS Python console but it doesn't give me the result.

```
>>> class color:
...   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
...   CYAN = '\033[96m'
...   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
...   BLUE = '\033[94m'
...   GREEN = '\033[92m'
...   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
...   RED = '\033[91m'
...   BOLD = '\033[1m'
...   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
...   END = '\033[0m'
>>> print color.BOLD + 'Hello World !' + color.END
ESC[1mHello World !ESC[0m
>>> import sys
>>> from termcolor import colored, cprint
>>> print colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
ESC[31mhelloESC[0m ESC[32mworldESC[0m
```

Please help me to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Does your terminal support colors in the first place? Does it support ANSI escapes? Also I don't get what does `QTextBrowser` have to do with this. `QTextBrowser` doesn't support ANSI escapes, it uses HTML and CSS...

Comment: in my GUI there is a QTextBrowser. I want to bold some text there, through my code in a .py file. First I just tried them in qgis console and got above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QTextBrowser` is *not* a console. What you tried are console escapes. If you want to make the text bold in `QTextBrowser` use the [`insertHtml`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#insertHtml) method inherited from `QTextEdit` and use the appropriate HTML tags.